# Password paste does not run correctly in Autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following script that opens an incognito script from Chrome, clicks away the cooking and presses the login button.

```
!i::
 Run,  Chrome.exe -incognito,, Maximize
 Sleep, 500
 Mouseclick, left, 524, 77
 Sleep, 500
 Send https://stackoverflow.com/ {Enter}
 Sleep, 1500
 MouseClick, left, 337, 889
 Sleep, 1500
 MouseClick, left, 1616, 124
 Sleep, 500
 MouseClick, left, 845, 584
 Send <mail> {Enter}
 Sleep, 500
 MouseClick, left, 889, 677
 Send <password> {Enter}

return
```

It all works fine till the last part. When I am entering my password it does not recognize it. Which is strange cause when I copy paste the password from my script it does work. Any thoughts on whats going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you have some keys in your password which hold a special meaning in a send command (such as `!` for `Alt`). See [the documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) for these.

Answer (score 0):

Try to confirm your password with msgbox or set it to clipboard then paste to somewhere else manually and check, if all correct then tweak your code by sending as paste with Send, ^v

If still doesn't work, add some more info with altering your real password to something random and share the code which shows how you get it. Also, you can directly open a page with

```
Run,  Chrome.exe /incognito https://stackoverflow.com/,, Maximize
```

This still doesn't run chrome as maximized, neither your code, **on my system**. I would set it to maximize with ifwinactive then winmaximize after launching it.